# How to check if last column in Multicolumn Listbox has an entry?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a listbox with 3 columns. In some rows there is no entry in the third column (it was never populated). I want to test whether the third column for a particular row has an entry, like this:

```
if listbox1.list(i,2) = "" then
```

But this gives a run time error if there is no entry in the third column. I have also tried

if isnull(listbox1.list(i,2)) then

but again this produces a run-time error. I know I can get around this by using on error resume next, but I have a feeling there must be a better way.

Edit:

The error I get is "Could not get the List property. Invalid argument.". In my actual code I refer to .list(i,j) and it works fine when j= 0 and j = 1, but when j = 2 it errors. In the example I am testing there are NO ENTRIES in column 2 of the listbox whatsoever, but the listbox's columncount property is set to a value of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different ways:

```
If Len(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2)) = 0 Then
If IsEmpty(Me.ListBox1.List(i, 2)) Then
```

Comment: Thanks, but these won't work either. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Ah, I think I've found the problem. I was setting the listbox's RowSource property to a range with only two columns, so I guess that overrides the ColumnCount property.